# Fetch QuickBooks Cash flow report using C#

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I want to fetch statement of cash flow reports from Quick Books using C#. 
Is there any way (or) any query to fetch reports using Intuit SDK?.

Comment: Are you looking for QB Desktop or QB Online?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QBO, refer this sample code in C#-

```
ReportService reportService = new ReportService(context); 

//Date should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD 
reportService.accounting_method = "Accrual"; 
reportService.start_date = "1997-01-01"; 
reportService.end_date = "2014-12-18"; 
////reportService.classid = "2800000000000634813"; 
//reportService.date_macro = "Last Month"; 
reportService.summarize_column_by = "Month"; 


List<String> columndata = new List<String>(); 
columndata.Add("tx_date"); 
columndata.Add("dept_name"); 
string coldata = String.Join(",", columndata); 
reportService.columns = coldata; 

var report1 = reportService.ExecuteReport("GeneralLedger");
```

Just remember to change the report type and cols based on the docs-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0400_references/reports/cashflow